# As startActivityForResult() has been depreciated .How to get image from gallery in android with kotlin?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

As startActivityForResult() has been depreciated .How to get image from gallery in android with kotlin ?

Comment: Did you read [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result)? What have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

You can use registerForActivityResult instead of startActivityForResult.
Here is my code to get image from gallery in kotlin:

```
// class level
private val openGallery =
        registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) {
            if (it.resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                binding.imgProfile.load(it.data?.data)
            }
        }

// in onViewCreated
imgProfile.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK)
            intent.setType("image/*")
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
            openGallery.launch(intent)
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

// on button Lisnter put this code

```
buttonPressed.setOnClickListener {
                val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK)
                intent.type = "image/*"
                intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION
                openGallery.launch(intent)            
        }
```

// outside onCreate put this code

```
private val openGallery =     registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) {
            if (it.resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                backgroundImage.setImageURI(it.data?.data)
            }
        }
```